# Exchange 2003 default inheritance security setting at Server level

Tags: exchange-2003

What is the Exchange 2003 default inheritance security setting at Server level? inheritance enabled or not? If I set delegation at Administrative Group level I can see permission stops at server level because of inheritance current setting is 'do not inherit'. Is this default?